# Display wordpress category name and the related posts

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I want to display category name on top and then the posts belonging to the particular category below it.

This should happen for all of my 20 categories and the results show be displayed on one page.

This is something I was trying but it doesn't work.

```
<?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=finance-training-seminars&posts_per_page=-1&post-type=dt_portfolio' ); ?>
<ul>
<?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>

<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php endwhile; ?> 
</ul>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) to list all categories and then create a query for each category and show posts related to it, something like this:

```
<?php
$categories = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'category' ) );
foreach( $categories as $cat ) :
    $posts = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'     => 'dt_portfolio',
        'showposts'     => -1,
        'tax_query'     => array(
                               array(
                                   'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                   'terms'    => array( $cat->term_id ),
                                   'field'   => 'term_id'
                               )

                          )
    ) ); ?>

    <h3><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h3>

    <ul>
        <?php while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort. This is only listing all my categories but the related posts are not showing up. Just category names are displaying only.

Comment: @Damon are you sure the category is registered to `dt_portfolio`  post type?

Comment: Yes i am sure. I am getting all the listed taxonomies but not the posts related to them.

Comment: the code after the 'while($posts -> have_posts() )' seems to do nothing.

Comment: @Damon I tested the code, it should be working fine, please check the `$posts` variable with `var_dump` and see if something is preventing the posts to be loaded, also try `tax_query` instead of `category__in`

Comment: 'tax_query' returns all the posted items ignoring which category they belong to. I need to return items belonging to particular category

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: @Damon Glad i could be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    <?php 
      $rCateogry = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'CUSTOM_TAXONOMY_NAME' ); 
      $related = get_posts(array( 'post_type' => 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE',  'tax_query' => array(array(  'taxonomy' => 'CUSTOM_TAXONOMY_NAME', 'field'    => 'id', 'terms'    => $rCateogry, )), 'showposts' => -1, 'order' => 'DESC', 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) )); ?>
  <section id="discover">
    <h2>Related Posts</h2>
      <div class="singlepost">
        <?php if( $related ) foreach( $related as $post ) {
          setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <?php $cats = array();
                foreach($rCateogry as $c){
                    $cat = get_category( $c );
                    echo $cat->name;
                } ?>
        <?php } 
      wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
      </div>
  </section>
```

Replace "CUSTOM_TAXONOMY_NAME" with the taxonomy name and "CUSTOM_POST_TYPE" with post type name

Comment: Thanks but still nothing.

Comment: Replace this line of code and try, $related = get_posts( array( 'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'category', 'field'    => 'id', 'terms'    => $rCateogry, ), ), 'post_type'        =>'dt_portfolio', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)  ) ); ?>

Comment: still nothing. All m seeing is the text inside the h2 tag